# Hibernate Envers-Get all entities, revision numbers, revision dates and revision types of an Entity by its ID

Tags: hibernate-envers

Using Hibernate Envers I want to get all **entities**, **revision numbers**, **revision dates** and **revision types** of an Entity by its *ID*.

Currently I am doing this to obtain the entity, revision number and revision date:

```
public List<Alumno> obtenerAuditoriaAlumno(Long idAlumno) {

   AuditReader auditReader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager);
   List<Number> revisionNumbers = auditReader.getRevisions(Alumno.class, idAlumno);

   List<Alumno> auditoriaAlumno = new ArrayList<Alumno>();

   for (Number rev : revisionNumbers) {
      Alumno alumno = auditReader.find(Alumno.class, idAlumno, rev);
      Date revisionDate = auditReader.getRevisionDate(rev);

      alumno.setRevisionNumber(rev.intValue());
      //alumno.setRevisionType(revisionType); // GET THIS
      alumno.setRevisionDate(revisionDate);
      auditoriaAlumno.add(alumno);
  }
return auditoriaAlumno;
}
```

Is it possible to obtain it with one query?

Should I add these fields directly to the Entity?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would suggest you take a look at using `forRevisionsOfEntity`.  You access this method by using the `AuditReader` interface as follows:

```
auditReader.createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity( 
   YourAuditEntityClass.class,
   false,                       // false returns an array of entity and audit data
   true                         // selects the deleted audit rows
);
```

The important method argument here is the second argument as that influences the returned `Object` type.  When its `true`, you'll be returned the actual audited entity instances for each revision; however, when its `false` you'll be returned an  `Object[]` array of values of which are:

1. The entity instance.
2. The revision entity instance (where you can get the revision number and date)
3. The revision type, e.g. ADD, MOD, DEL.

HTH.